# How to force BigQueryIO.Write to create table in EU

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow

I'm running a Dataflow streaming pipeline. During it I'm creating multiple tables, names of those are changing during pipeline execution. My Dataflow pipeline runs in EU. I've added following setting to options:

```
options.setZone("europe-west1-b");
```

I'm using `BigQueryIO.Write` to save data to GBQ using following code:

```
BigQueryIO.Write
    .named(...)
    .to(DynamicTableName.of(...))
    .withCreateDisposition(BigQueryIO.Write.CreateDisposition.CREATE_IF_NEEDED)
    .withSchema(...)
    .withWriteDisposition(BigQueryIO.Write.WriteDisposition.WRITE_APPEND)
```

Tables created by that snipped are located in US. How can I force `BigQueryIO.Write` to create tables in EU?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Obviusly... location is set on dataset level, not table level. Thus the location of dataset in which table is created should be specified accordingly.